# How to make a Google Sheets cell output any string?

Tags: google-sheets

I can type `1+1` in a cell, and then it appears unchanged.

However typing typing `+1` or `=1`, it's not being taken as text, due to the prefixes, and it's shown differently.

What to type so a cell has shows the string `+1` as output?

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer `=ASC("+1")`

Answer (score 1):

A shorter solution, one which may be familiar from Microsoft Excel, is to start the content with a single quote (`'`):

[image]